# nginx reverse proxy subdomain problems

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple services. I'm running (phpmyadmin, MySQL, graphql api, nextjs-apps etc.). I'm going to refer to my domain as `example-domain.de`

I previously used `mysql.example-domain.de` to access phpmyadmin, I now want to change this to `phpmyadmin.example-domain.de` because I want to use `mysql.example-domain.de` as TCP proxy for my MySQL server.

The appropriate nginx config:

```
server {
        server_name mysql.example-domain.de www.example-domain.de;

        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

                include fastcgi_params;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-domain-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-domain-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

This configuration works to serve phpmyadmin on `mysql.example-domain.de`, but if I add or change the `server_name` to: 
`server_name mysql.example-domain.de www.mysql.example-domain.de phpmyadmin.example-domain.de www.phpmyadmin.example-doman.de` 
or 
`server_name phpmyadmin.example-domain.de www.phpmyadmin.example-doman.de`

I can't access `phpmyadmin.example-domain.de`

Yes, I renewed the let's encrypt certificate using certbot.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "I can't access phpmyadmin.example-domain.de" mean exactly? What is the request you made? What is the error?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen i changed `server_name mysql.example-domain.de[...]` to `server_name phpmyadmin.example-domain.de` and i cannot access it. 404 not found (browser). Every other setting remains the same, it should not be needed to change anything else

Comment: Did you reload nginx configuration after changing config?

Comment: yes, i restarted the nginx server with `sudo systemctl restart nginx` (tested config using `ngixn -t`)

Comment: Does your DNS record for the domains point to correct IP address?

Comment: yes, the `404 Not found` screen comes from nginx.
`
404 not found
------------------
nginx / 1.18.0 (ubuntu)
`

Comment: There MUST BE a DNS CNAME record with your domain registrar for `phpmyadmin.example-domain.de` or NGINX will not be able to lookup this DNS record and find your IP address.

Comment: just to clarify, yes - there is a DNS Record for phpmyadmin.example-domain.de

Comment: i thought about that one of the `location[...]` entries is maybe somehow wrong, but the same work with the old subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I don't know why or how, but it's working and I'm going leave it there.

I didn't change any config files in the last few days, and when I tried it today, it worked.

subdomain was created about 3 weeks ago so that couldn't be the problem.